# Split txt data into columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, split, multiple-columns

I have a .txt data set in the following format:

```
01/01/2018 ['cat', 'bear', 'ant']
01/02/2018 ['horse', 'wolf', 'elephant']
01/03/2018 ['parrot', 'bird', 'fish]
```

And I would like to use PYTHON and set it in 2 columns in the following format:

```
  'Date'       'Animal'

01/01/2018       cat
01/01/2018       bear   
01/01/2018       ant
01/02/2018       horse
01/02/2018       wolf
01/02/2018       elephant
01/03/2018       parrot
01/03/2018       bird
01/03/2018       fish
```

(the txt file is actually longer but it was simplified for a better understanding). I am not sure how to proceed: read_csv or open (but then it will read it like an object
)?. Should I set delimiters? I tried several things but nothing works.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pandas to create the table:

```
import ast

import pandas as pd

dates = []
animals = []
lines = []

# Read file lines
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for l in lines:
    # Spliting date and animals
    date_string, animals_string = l.split(' ', maxsplit=1)
    # Safely evaluate animals list
    animals_list = ast.literal_eval(animals_string)
    # Duplicate date the amount of animals in that date
    dates.extend([date_string] * len(animals_list))
    # Append animals
    animals.extend(animals_list)

# Create dataframe for the dates and animals
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates, 'Animal': animals})

# Print the dataframe
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         Date    Animal
0  01/01/2018       cat
1  01/01/2018      bear
2  01/01/2018       ant
3  01/02/2018     horse
4  01/02/2018      wolf
5  01/02/2018  elephant
6  01/03/2018    parrot
7  01/03/2018      bird
8  01/03/2018      fish
```